# Fullscreen Page Background without Plugin

Tags: images, custom-background, screen-layout

I am using the Advanced Layout builder for editing pages in the Enfold theme. I've seen many solutions via code editing or plugin additions, but I am behind a controlled environment and do not have access to FTP (access to functions.php, files, etc) nor WP plugins.

The home page can be set to a fullscreen background via the `Theme > Customize > Appearance` , but I want to add a *fullscreen* background image to other pages. The only option I see is in the settings of a `1/1 column > Styling > Background Image`. But this background is bounded and does not fill the full-width of the page.

How can I add a full-width background image without a plugin, or functions.php?

Comment: What CSS have you tried? Keep in mind that 3rd party theme/plugin support is off topic here, we can't provide support or help for the Enfold theme or the Advanced Layout builder plugin. If it's just changing the background fit from containing the image to covering the entire element then that can be done with pure CSS and no WordPress knowledge is needed to do that ( Pure CSS questions should be asked on StackOverflow )

Comment: Okay good to know, thanks! I hadn't done a lot of CSS and saw theme/plugin-related answers and tags on here. Since this is all related to using WP, I was not getting help on other sites -  but will keep in mind for future questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found a solution by using a different type of section.

The issue was having was the max width was capped at the container's width which could not be set and looked like this:
[image]

But after changing the section type from a 1/1 to a color section, I was able to have the background image fill the full-width of the page like this:
[image]

Code wise looks like:

```css
/* Color section container width */
#section-container-width .container {
  width: 100% !important;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```